# Angular $http calls error on 200 response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code used within an Angular service:-

```
var formData = function (data) {
   var fd = new FormData();
   angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
      fd.append(key, value);
   });
   return fd;
}

var updateUserPic = function (profilePic, callback, userId) {
   var userId = userId || FRAME_API.proxyUserId; // jshint ignore:line
   if (!_.isFunction(callback)) {
      throw new Error('You must provide a callback function.');
   } 
   $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/Learn/PostUserProfile.ashx?action=profilepic&userid=' + userId,
      data: {up_picfile: profilePic},
      transformRequest: formData,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined}
   }).success(function (data, status, headers, config){
      callback([data, status, headers, config]);
      return;
   }).error(function (data, status){
      console.log([status,data]);
      callback(false);
      return;
   });
};
```

Inspecting using the Network tab in Chrome's Developer Tools shows that there is a `200 OK` response.  Also the data goes through as expected.  However, the problem is that the `error` callback is the only one ever called regardless of the fact that it has a status of 200.  Also the `data` and `status` parameters come in as `undefined`.

Any reason this would be the case?

The response from the server is this:

```
{status: 'success', path: 'assets/profile/profilepicture.png'}
```

Also, note that this response cannot be changed by me.  It is coming from a vendor's script running on the server which I cannot access.

Comment: Can you show us what data comes from server? see it in network tab in developer tools

Comment: it's possible that angular waits for json formatted data and you are returning wrong data

Comment: @karaxuna Added the response to the questions.

Comment: yeah that's the problem, returned data is not json

Comment: So do I need to use an interceptor or some other kind of response transformer to get it to function properly?

Comment: you should build right json on the server and then send it to client

Comment: check httpinterceptor, maybe you are rejecting promise somewhere

Comment: @karaxuna I found that the default response transformer is trying to run JSON.parse() on the returned string thus causing it to fail.  I'm working on a solution that transforms my invalid response json to valid response json before passing it back to angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a custom response transformer to turn it to valid JSON:

```
var responseTransformer = function (data) {

   return data.replace('status', '"status"')
              .replace('\'success\'', '"success"')
              .replace('path', '"path"')
              .replace('\'assets/profile/profilepicture.png\'',
                       '"assets/profile/profilepicture.png"');

};
```

This made it work just fine.

Comment: In my case the `transformRequest: formData,` was missing in my request, that solved it.

Answer (score 2):

returned data should look like this:

```
{ "status": "success", "path": "assets/profile/profilepicture.png" }
```

note " must be instead of '

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control of the server-side code thus that cannot change.

Comment: That's not the problem

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 you are right, maybe the result he showed is already parsed object

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 maybe he's rejecting promise somewhere in interceptor, how do you think?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the server was returning a "File Not Found" string, while the native $http in Angular was expecting a response of type "application/json". So even though the status code was 200 OK, it was entering the .error part of the http method.

To fix this, I had to return a JSON Object from the server.